# Need to turn python 3 script to python 2.7 script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I had this Python 3 script and now I need it to run on Python 2,
from what I have read **urilib** should change to **urlib2**.
But it looks like there was a change in the encoding class.
because I get this error:

```
16:29:27 + python p.py
16:29:27 Traceback (most recent call last):
16:29:27   File "p.py", line 20, in <module>
16:29:27     binary_data = params.encode(encoding=repr,errors=strict)
16:29:27 NameError: name 'strict' is not defined
```

***This is my Python 3 script:***

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import sys
import os
url = 'http://google.com' 
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({ 
'profile': 'dev' ,
'KEY':'bdi.key' ,
}) 
binary_data = params.encode(encoding='ascii',errors='strict') 
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, binary_data).read()
```

***This is my Python 2 script:***

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from contextlib import closing
import sys
import os
url = 'http://google.com'
params = urllib.urlencode({
'profile': 'dev' ,
'KEY':'bdi.key' ,
})
binary_data = params.encode(encoding=repr,errors=strict)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, binary_data).read()
```

How Can I get it to work? 
I have never used Python before and this is a maintenance script that I am trying to keep alive :)

Comment: `binary_data = params.encode(encoding='ascii', errors='strict')`? Notice I used quotes `'` around the wordc `strict` and `repr` to tell Python they were strings and not names.

Comment: `strict` should be a `string`
encoding should also be a string (`"ascii"`)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in string encoding function, namely `errors` parameter. You should put `strict` into quotes, since variable `strict` doesn't exist.

So, it should be like this:

```
binary_data = params.encode(encoding=repr, errors='strict')
```